# Invoke Inner class method having parameters using reflection

Tags: java, methods, reflection

I am trying to test my code though knowing using reflection is not a good way of testing. I have a outer class as public having private inner class with a public method as below,

```
public class Outer {

    private class Inner {
        private int var = 1;

        public Inner(int a) {
            System.out.println("___");
        }

        public void test(int a) {
            System.out.println("Hey");
        }
    }
}
```

My main java class looks like below

```
main() {
    Outer b = new Outer();
    System.out.println(b);
    Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("car.Outer$Inner");

    Constructor<?> constructor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Outer.class, 1);

    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Object c = constructor.newInstance(b,b);

    Method method = c.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(c, 1);
}
```

This is throwing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: car.Outer$Inner.test()
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
>       at car.A.main(A.java:36)

How to invoke inner class method taking parameter using reflection?

Comment: can you check your method is in the class or not ?

Comment: That is inside the class only. The same works for the methods with no parameter.

Comment: You need to supply the argument class(es) in the call to `getDeclaredMethod()`. In this case, `c.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test", int.class)` should work.

Comment: You are the life saver. Thanks Man:-)

Comment: Looks like such a question was already asked today: [Java reflection: access private method inside inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529608/java-reflection-access-private-method-inside-inner-class) In this case OP got a step further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the argument class(es) in the call to `getDeclaredMethod()`. When you call `getDeclaredMethod()`, the first argument is the name of the method you want looked up and any remaining arguments are the classes of the argument(s) to the method you want. This is how `getDeclaredMethod()` distinguishes between overloaded method names to get one particular method. Since you have supplied no additional arguments, `getDeclaredMethod()` is looking for a method named `test` that takes no arguments. You're getting an exception because you have no such method in class `Outer$Inner`. The only `test` method you do have takes an `int` parameter`, so the following should do what you want:

```
Method method = c.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test", int.class);
```

Here, `int.class` is the `Class` object corresponding to the primitive argument type `int`.